# With statement equals try catch

Tags: python, try-catch, with-statement

I'm still having some trouble understanding python's `with` statement after reading some papers on it. Do these two codes do the same things? Does `with` do the same thing as `try catch`?

```
try:
  a = A()
  #do something with a


with A() as a:
  #do something with a
```

Comment: The `with` is a context manager. A context manager's work is to effectively manage resources and make sure that upon an operation's completion, these resources will be successfully released.

Comment: Good explanation Vasillis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the with statement is a "context manager". Think of like this:

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    do stuff in file
```

Now, when the code above is finished doing stuff, and the execution leaves the with statement, the file will no longer be open.

Please look this over, it gives a good explanation: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/